# how to transfer a float from one scene to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I am making a fps shooter game with unity 3d and I am trying to add a in game currency system but in order to do this I need to transfer a float called coins that is on my players movement script from the level scene to the store scene in order for it to be spent and displayed on screen as a UI dose anybody know how I can do this thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

Do not store variables in scripts where they do not belong. There are multiple solutions to this problem:

1. Option is to create a `ScriptableObject` that contains variables that need to be transferred. It is instantiated in the editor by you and then assigned as an asset to your player prefab. Instead of setting a variable in the player itself, the player just sets a variable in this storage.
   This storage can be anything, from a single variable ([see this video for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=raQ3iHhE_Kk)) to big systems like Unitys [Tilemap System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tilemap.html).
2. You create a component that is attached to a game object that resides in the "Dont Destroy On Load" scene. This can be done by creating a monobehaviour script and calling `DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject)` in its `Start` method. Additionally, you can make it a singleton and access it from everywhere. For reference see [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/116010/105730) from the game dev stackexchange.

To be honest, I always try to go with the first one. If you want some variables to persist in a "game state" (that's what its called in Unreal), then you create it externally and reference it throughout you session. There are really a lot of situational approaches and there is no real right or wrong, but you should always keep in mind that a class should only serve a single purpose and a player script that moves the player and stores the current stats (that should live longer than the player itself) is usually a bad approach.

Comment: I'd agree, to start out don't touch `DontDestroyOnLoad`. There are so many things that can go wrong with it. I'd also suggest avoiding singletons, while useful, they make components too tightly coupled.

Comment: To complement your answer, there is another option too that may be suitable for currency, because you expect (usually) it to be persistent too.
Save the variable on disk, like PlayerPrefs (but it is not really recommended for this, because it is not secure) or another fancy way like BinaryFormatter.